# Why was "type" the correct answer in "Often : frequently :: kind : _____"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, analogy

The question is:

> Often : frequently :: kind : _____

or,

> *Often* is to *frequently* as *kind* is to *_____*

And the options given were

1. *kindly*
2. *type*

The correct answer was *type*.

But why isn't *kindly* also possible?

Comment: What was the context? What knowledge or skills were you being tested on?

Comment: Logical reasoning

Comment: Note that although *often* and *frequently* are strictly only ever adverbs of frequency, that *type* can be used as both a noun and a verb, while *kindly* is usable as both an adjective and an adverb.  Moreover, *often* and *kind* and *kindly* are Germanic in origin, but *type* and *frequently* have Latin etymons not Germanic ones, despite the Germanic *-ly* derivational suffix. *Kind(ly)* and *oft(en)* are from Old English, while *type* and *frequent(ly)* came to us via the French infusion of glosses in Middle English; the last is the newest, almost Early Modern English in origin.

Answer (score 5):

*Often* is an *adverb*, and *frequently* is a synonymous adverb;
*kind* (variety) is a *noun*, and *type* is a synonymous noun;
however, *kind* (sympathetic) is an *adjective*, and *kindly* is a corresponding *adverb*;

They clearly want you to keep the part of speech the same.

On the other hand, as the comments reminded me, [*kindly*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/kindly) can be used as an adjective, in which case it is more or less a synonym of *kind*; because of this, they should probably accept *kindly* as an answer as well.

Comment: So putting kindly makes it wrong ? Can we make any relationship between them like type and kind are synonyms I agree but kind has another meaning which is also similar to kindly right. If we go by that relationship then isn't kindly also possible?

Comment: There isn't any "right" or "wrong". It's all opinions of whoever wrote the test. Grammar is not a matter of proportions.

Comment: I need to challenge the question as i believe kindly can be one of the answer as no relationship is given . Please provide me some valid argument which may be sufficient to challenge it .

Comment: I should think a kindly old man would use *kindly* as an adjective.

Comment: I agree with this answer. At the same time, I think it would also make sense to point out, that this kind of questions expect the person being tested to know how these tests usually work and what kind of logic to apply. Because otherwise, just one example allows you to infer all kinds of relationships between the two words that would yield different answers being seen as correct.

Comment: @Amarkumar Can you substitute "kind" with "kindly" in any sentence? e.g "He was very kind to them" Not so much. Can we say " A tram is a kind (or) type of bus" and in "He travels frequently (or) often by train“. In these examples, the words *kind/type* and *frequently/often* are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

> Often (adverb) is to frequently (adverb) as kind (adjective/noun) is to _____ (?)

And the options give were close synonyms

**kindly** - this would be correct if "kind" were an adverb - but it is not: *"He kind took her hand."

**kindly** - this is wrong if kindly is an adjective: "He was a kindly man."

**kindly** - this is correct if kindly is an adverb: "He kindly gave me some money."

**type** - this is correct if "kind" is a noun. "I want this kind of car."

The question is ridiculous.

Comment: I agree the question is ridiculous, but what does your "true" mean? Are you confusing right and wrong with good and evil and true and false?

Comment: That's already been corrected - I was thinking of the analogy/logic but decided "correct" is simpler.

Comment: So is there  any material or valid argument you can provide which can mark this question as ambiguous? This is a standard exam questions (IIT entrance)

Comment: I thought I had done that in my answer... If you are going to appeal, you will have to do your own work if that is not enough.

Comment: You said that `type - this is true if "kind" is a noun.` How is *type* true?

Comment: @Amarkumar Can you substitute "kind" with "kindly" in any of the examples contained in Greybeard's answer? Not so much. Can we say " A tram is a kind (or) type of bus" and in  "He travels frequently (or)often by train“. In these examples the words *kind/type* *frequently/often* are interchangeable.